# partial sums formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I have found the partial sum formula and it is given by $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ir^{i-1}=a_1(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r})$$
I am just a little confused about the $a_1$ term and how we use this, for example I thought the sum for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{ex}{e^x}\right)^n$$ 
Would be given by $(\frac{1-(exe^{-x})^n}{1-exe^-x})$ but apparently it is not? can someone explain to me how you would use this formula to get the right sum for this series?

Comment: The initial value of $i$ is different in your two sums.

Comment: The final value of $i$ is also different in your two sums.

Comment: Would you need to take out $exe^{-x}$ as a factor to get it in the right form?

Comment: Hard to tell what you meant to ask. You wrote $a_i\,$ in the first sum, did you mean $a_1$ maybe?

Comment: $a_i$ should be a constant-without the index $i$. Please make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{ex}{e^x}\right)^n
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\dfrac{ex}{e^x}\right)^i \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{e^x}{ex} \left(\dfrac{ex}{e^x}\right)^{i-1} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\mathop\to\infty} \dfrac{e^x}{ex} \dfrac{1-(exe^{-x})^n}{1-exe^{-x}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac{e^x}{ex} \dfrac{1}{1-exe^{-x}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac{e^{2x}}{ex(e^x-ex)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac{e^{2x-1}}{xe^x-ex^2} \\
\end{array}$$